# If X and Y are sequential tangents to a group G at the identity matrix, show that X+Y is also.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, limits

If X and Y are sequential tangents to a group G at the identity matrix, show that X+Y is also.

Definition: X is a sequential tangent vector to G at the identity matrix I if there is a sequence $<A_m>$ of members of G, and a sequence $<a_m>$ of real numbers, such that 
$A_m$ $\to$ I and $\frac{(A_m - I)}{a_m}$ $\to$ X as m $\to$ $\infty$

Note that G is closed under matrix multiplication.

Since X is a sequential tangent vector, there is a sequence $<A_m>$ of members of G, and a sequence $<a_m>$ of real numbers, such that 
$A_m$ $\to$ I and $\frac{(A_m - I)}{a_m}$ $\to$ X as m $\to$ $\infty$

Since Y is a sequential tangent vector, there is a sequence $<B_m>$ of members of G, and a sequence $<b_m>$ of real numbers, such that 
$B_m$ $\to$ I and $\frac{(B_m - I)}{b_m}$ $\to$ X as m $\to$ $\infty$

So I know X+Y = $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ $\frac{(A_m - I)}{a_m}$ + $\frac{(B_m - I)}{b_m}$ =  $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ $\frac{a_m B_m + b_m A_m - a_m I - b_m I}{a_m b_m} $

Let $C_m$ - I = $a_m B_m + b_m A_m - a_m I - b_m I$, then  $C_m$ = $a_m B_m + b_m A_m - a_m I - b_m I$ + I

Note $C_m$ approaches I and $a_m b_m$ approaches 0 as m approaches infinity.

The only problem is how do I show that $C_m$ is in G? The only elements that are in G are matrices and products of matrices in $<A_m>$ and $<B_m>$.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong $C_m$. What happens if you use $C_m=A_mB_m$ instead? At least if you assume additionally that $a_m=b_m$ that ought to give something interesting. Can you dispose of that additional assumption somehow?

Comment: If C$_m$ = $A_m B_m$, $C_m$ still approaches 1. But, Why can we assume $a_m$ = $b_m$? How do I know the limit of ($C_m$ - I)/($a_m$ $b_m$) is X+Y?